# Inbound Email Service - Reply to Address

Tags: apex-email-service

quick question, our company sends a lot of emails to our email to case service from a webpage which sends email from noreply email address but uses the replyto address as the customer address.

They all tell me switching this on our exchange server is phishing and somehow they think doing this in Salesforce isnt. But I digress, my question is on the email object can I access the replyto address?

Answer (score 0):

seems there is indeed a reply to field on the object
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_inbound_email.htm&type=5